# Find all non-integers in column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some corrupted rows in my large CSV file where some data values get shifted due to missing line breaks. This results in values appearing in the wrong column header. For eg. if three columns exists in my table, , , , after corruption, I start to see values like , , .

Is there a way for me to drop all rows where for e.g. I see a non-int in a row that I know should, in fact, be an Int?

Comment: you should provide with input dataframe and expected output dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is loop through the lines, and when the `lines.split(",").count()` doesn't equal what you want, you can filter it out. Something like this:

```
import scala.io.Source
val n = 5 //or how many columns you require
Source.fromFile(input_file).getLines().toSeq.map(_.split(",")).filter(_.count == n)
```

This should do what you want :)